# Read a specific value from javascript hashmap

Tags: javascript

I am trying a very basic javascript map example

```
   var map1 = {'myKey1':11, 'mykey2':22};

   var t = map1['mykey1'];
   alert(t);
```

But the alert always gives me 'undefined', it should give me '11'

please guide what i am doing wrong

Comment: hashmap? You mean an object? You also have a typo in your capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake there mate, notice that in your map1 object there is no `mykey1` key actually, there is a `myKey1` key however, containing a capital K

Comment: opes, u right, thanks